# GMSPlacePickerViewController always return error - There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-static-api

hope everyone doing well.
I'm developing an iOS application which needs to share location through google maps and display map static image in a screen corresponding to the selected location.
I've done some researches and found GMSPlacePickerViewController is the best option. I've set up api key in google cloud platform and restricted it with app bundle ID and API restrictions (Maps SDk, Places API and Maps static API). I've enable billing for the account.
Now each time I going to GMSPlacePickerViewController, the map just loading and dismissing itself. It throws 2 errors.

1 - "The application's bundle identifier does not match one of the 
    allowed iOS applications for the API key. See the developer's guide 
    (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) for how to 
    configure bundle restrictions on API keys."
2 - "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your 
    API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please 
    use the Google Developers Console to update your API key 
    configuration if request from this IP or referer should be 
    allowed."

I don't know why this happened as I've set correct bundle ID and I generated credential as API key.

I request you to advice me to get out this and please tell me if there is any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the Place Picker has been deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. Please note that the old users that used Places SDK for iOS/Android are the only one who can still use the Place Picker during the deprecation period. The use of Places SDK for both platforms are now through enabling Places API and does not support the use of Place Picker anymore. You may see the deprecation notice in https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker.

In addition to this, Google is conducting a review on what drives the users to use the Place Picker, if you are interested, kindly add your answer in the form mentioned in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760).

Should you need further assistance, kindly file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel.